# NodeJS FS not returning data from multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
    var market = fs.readdirSync(__dirname+"/c/")
    console.log(market)
    for(i in market){
        console.log(market[i]) // <----- shows contents of folder
        fs.readFile(market[i],'utf-8',function(err,data){
            console.log(data) // <---- retruns undefined 
        })
    }
```

So I thought this would be alot easier, but clearly i'm messing up somewhere.
as you can see, `console.log(market[i])`shows the contents of the folder, but if i try to read them, i just get returned "undefined", anyone have a clue on why this is happening? I'm trying to read the data of each file, basically later im going to store it, and send it, but thats not a problem right now, the bigger concern is it not even reading the data from the files :U.

Comment: Add a `console.log(err)` inside your `fs.readFile()` callback to see if there's an error being returned and what that error is.  Always look at error values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a full path to the `readFile`, while `readdirSync` returns you only file names, so the correct code would be:

```
   var market = fs.readdirSync(__dirname+"/c/")
    console.log(market)
    for(i in market){
        console.log(market[i]) // <----- shows contents of folder
        fs.readFile(__dirname + "/c/" + market[i],'utf-8',function(err,data) {
            console.log(data) // <---- retruns undefined 
        })
    }
```